# Analyzing multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have data in 10 individual csv files. Each csv file just has one row of data entires (500000 data points, no headers etc.). Three questions:

1. How can I transform the data to be one column with 500000 rows?
2. Is it better to import them into one numpy array: 500000 x 10 to analyze them. If so, how can one do this?
3. Or is it better to import them into one DataFrame 500000 x 10, to analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a list of file names `files`.  Then:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in files], ignore_index=True)
```

1. `df` is a 10 x 500000 dataframe.  Make it a 500000 x 10 with `df.T`

Answers to 2 and 3 depends on your task.

Comment: @deserthiker: You may also use df.as_matrix() to convert to numpy.

Answer (score 0):

First, read all 10 csv:

```
import os, csv, numpy
import pandas as pd

my_csvs = os.listdir('path to folder with 10 csvs') #selects all files in folder
list_of_columns = []
os.chdir('path to folder with 10 csvs')

for file in my_csvs:
    column = []
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            column.append(row)
    list_of_columns.append(column)
```

This is how you get a list of lists-columns. Next transform them to pandas df or numpy or whatever you feel comfortable to work with.